# How to convert Long to Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to do something like this:

```
fun process(minutes: Int) = 0

fun test() {
    process(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60) // error: Int expected
}
```

and if I try `process((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60) as Int)` I get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

So how can I convert Long to Int?

Comment: You can scan the [API reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html), or explore functions available on classes via your IDE code-completion to find helpful things in Kotlin.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`Long.toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/to-int.html):

```
process((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60).toInt())
```

Comment: yep, unlike in C++, cast is not a conversion

Answer (score 7):

↓Long.toInt() is not safety. because long to int is shrink

```
val l: Long
l.toInt()　←not safety! when out of int range
```

Please add this function to arbitrary kt file instead.
Then, a method called toIntOrNull is added to Long.
This method returns null if it tries to convert long to int, when it does not fit within int range.

```
fun Long.toIntOrNull(): Int? {
    return if (this < Int.MIN_VALUE || this > Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        null
    } else {
        this.toInt()
    }
}
```

or

```
fun Long.toIntOrNull(): Int? {
    val i = this.toInt()
    return if (i.toLong() == this) i else null
}
```

Comment: Or use `Math.toIntExact` from Java.

Comment: @AndrejHerich `Math.toIntExact` doesn't work as the solution above. If long value is out the int values bounds it will throw an ArithmeticException, I prefer solution Tom's solution.

Comment: Agree w/ Tom here. You need to make sure you're converting a value within [Int.MIN_VALUE, Int.MAX_VALUE] if going from Long to Int.